# Continuous function $f$ such that $X^n f$ is of the class $C^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f: R \rightarrow R$ be continuous on $R$ ( with $f(0)=0$ if necessary) and of class $C^\infty$ on $R \setminus \{0\}$. Assume that for each $n \in N$ the function $g_n(x)=x^n f(x)$, for $x \in R$, is of the class $C^n$ on $R$.

Is it true that $f$ is of the class $C^\infty$ on $R$   ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the absolute value function $x \mapsto \begin{cases}
  x, & \mbox{if } x \ge 0 \\
  -x, & \mbox{if } x \lt 0 
\end{cases}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: It's the first thing that comes to mind.. =)